# 1% of Users get new Session ID on each page request

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, session-cookies

We just upgraded to IIS7 and have had intermittent issues with SESSION variables. In a nutshell a very low percentage of users are getting new SESSION IDs with each page request. Clearing cookies has solved this problem for just about every use I've come across.

My question is... Is there a way to programmatically do this? It's been a lower percentage of calls of people unable to login/can't get a certain application to work, so it's not a HUGE deal, but we are having to walk people through the process of clearing cookies all day. I haven't read of, nor seen a way to force users to clear cookies.

Most other questions on here are uses having this issue everywhere, as if there is a programmatic error. Our applications work fine, it's just a small percentage of users who used our applications on our old server can't get new session cookies from the new server.

We were running IIS6/CF9 and we upgraded to IIS7/CF10. This problem is cross browser. We have seen it turn up in IE, FF, and Chrome.

--EDIT--

If a user clears cookies and goes to domian.com and then to sub.domain.com, the domain.com cookie takes precedent and the browser I guess never returns the sub.domain.com cookie it gets from the sub.domain.com server. Turning on J2EE cookies on sub.domain.com fixes the issue, I guess, but the clients still run around with a cookie from domain.com. domain cookies is whatever is set by default... i.e. we don't set it to anything in app.cfc. I have no idea how it is set on domain.com.

Comment: Consider this just a random thought: have you tried to switch between J2EE and 'classic' sessions? Any difference?

Comment: Currently we are messing with an affected machine. On the page in question is has a CFID cookie form domain.com and sub.domain.com. On my machine on the same page I only have cookies from sub.domain.com and mine is working fine. We have tried switching TOO J2EE and thought we saw no difference. We might try that again.

Comment: We just switched to J2EE and it's holding... currently, and we didn't clear have to clear cookies to get it done. Still strange that on THAT machine it has two CFID cookies and on mine it does not. Why would there be a cookie with a CFID from domain.com on sub.domain.com. When we dump COOKIE var in coldfusion we get two identical cookies. When we view the cookie data in firebug, they are indeed different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Application.cfc do you have domain cookies set to true?

Comment: Here is what we did but not sure if there is a better solution. We don't maintain domain.com. We maintain sub.domain.com. domain.com is on a different server. If a user clears cookies and goes to domian.com and then to sub.domain.com, the domain.com cookie takes precedent and the browser I guess never returns the sub.domain.com cookie it gets from the sub.domain.com server. Turning on J2EE cookies on sub.domain.com fixes the issue, I guess, but the clients still run around with a cookie from domain.com. domain cookies is whatever is set by default... i.e. we don't set it to anything in app.cfc

Comment: I am guessing domain.com has domain cookies set to true. Since before we were running CF9 and IIS6 and they were running IIS7, that when we upgraded to their version of IIS it somehow decided that it was a good time to start using those domain cookies on our sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be related to the [session fixation Hotfix](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/security-hotfix-coldfusion-8-8.html) Adobe introduced in February last year. Was your CF9 server fully patched?

In short, CF now issues new CFID/TOKEN values on every session and won't use existing cookie values (to prevent session hijacking). Make sure your app is writing these new values to cookies and not allowing existing cookie values to be used.

Here's a [detailed explanation](http://cfsimplicity.com/4/coldfusion-security-hotfix-changes-session-behaviour) As pointed out in the comments on that post, using J2EE sessions is indeed one way of solving the problem.